# Asp.net MVC 4 DataAnnotation Language on Host Locaweb

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, host, unobtrusive-validation, multiple-languages

I'm developing a website Application. I'm using asp.net MVC 4 with .net 4.5 framework. I'm having some problems with language validation messages. In my PC and work PC the validations show in brazilian portuguese, as I'd like. But, when I publish in Host (Locaweb.com.br) all the language messages show in english. I have translated the jquery validate file messages to PT-BR, but the problem goes on. 
I don't like to write custom messages in models (although this way solve my problem).

why the language change in the host? Anyone could help me?

ps: the IIS in the host is in english, but the host suport man says it couldn't interfere in my problem.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should ann this section in your `Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This will tell MVC to use not default server culture but the one that you need.

Also you should add Globalize scripts set on your master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Globalize.culture("pt-BR");
</script>
```

Comment: @Guilherme i added more info.

Comment: Do I need reference a script file? I had a script error (globalize is not defined)

Comment: @Guilherme yeap, you need.

Comment: @Guilherme just install globalize.js from nuget and you need refference to main file and your culture file

Comment: Well, I tryed it, but maybe the iis is not accepting the "pt-BR" globalization. I tryed changed to "en-US" in locahost, and the messages languages changed to english, after changed to "pt-BR" and the messages changed to portuguese. But when upload to host, where iis is in english, nothing happens.